# 'AppDelegate' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

```
let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

I am trying to create an instance of AppDelegate in swift 5 but getting below error.
'AppDelegate' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
This same code I am using in swift 4.2 and its working fine for below ios 13 versions too.

Check below Image for error.

[image]

Comment: The code you posted at the top of the question is not the same code you show in the error screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps you marked your own AppDelegate with an `@available` attribute. But you have not shown that code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you might set the following

```
@available(iOS x.x, *)
@UIApplicationMain
```

In your `AppDelegate`

you can remove that or you can change the minimum deployment target with your supportive `iOS` version

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is

```
let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

add **@UIApplicationMain** this as well.

remove ().